# error .findLast is not a function jest test

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

During the develop of a test with jest in Angular I got this error:

**TypeError: columnDefs.findLast is not a function**

This is the method I´m trying to test:

```
onKeyDown(key: any) {
    const columnDefs = this.params.columnApi.columnModel.columnDefs;

    const lastColumnEnabled = columnDefs.findLast((col: any) => {
      if (col.cellEditorParams?.hasOwnProperty('isDisabled')) {
        if (
          typeof col.cellEditorParams.isDisabled !== 'function' &&
          col.cellEditorParams.isDisabled === false 
        )
          return col;
        if (
          typeof col.cellEditorParams.isDisabled === 'function' &&
          col.cellEditorParams.isDisabled(this.params.data, col.field) === false
        ) {
          return col;
        }
      } else {
        return col;
      }
    });
```

When I mock the columnDefs value I made sure it´s an array for findLast to be able to iterate.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your version of Typescript could be the problem - I am having the same issue on TS 4.3.5

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48829) you will need to be running Typescript > 5.0.0

I also understand that the version of TS is limited (pegged) by the version of Angular, and [according to this info](https://marco.dev/angular-typescript-node), not even Angular 16 supports TS 5

I have resolved this for myself by using [lodash .findLast](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/find-last/)

Comment: At last I resolved using .filter instead